# jBoss add-user.bat does not see the new realm

Tags: jboss

I created a new realm in `standalone.xml` and now I'm trying to create a new user in that realm. When I use full command like

```
add-user -a -r realm-name -u user -p password
```

I get the error:

```
JBAS015281: The user supplied realm name 'realm-name' does not match the realm name discovered from the property file(s) 'ApplicationRealm'.
```

When I run just `add-user`, it promts to choose realm, and there are only applicationrealm and managementrealm in the list.

Here's my snippets from `standalone.xml`:

1) Domain

```
<security-domain name="realm-domain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
         <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
             <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
         </login-module>
         <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
             <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/rt-users.properties"/>
             <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/rt-roles.properties"/>
             <module-option name="realm" value="realm-name"/>
             <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

2) Realm

```
<security-realm name="realm-name">
   <authentication>
     <local default-user="$local"/>
     <jaas name="realm-domain"/>
   </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy `mgmt-users.properties` (or `application-users.properties`) to for example `myfile.properties`.

Change the realm in `myfile.properties`; edit the line

```
#$REALM_NAME=ManagementRealm$ This line is used by the add-user utility ...
```

to

```
#$REALM_NAME=realm-name$ This line is used by the add-user utility ...
```

Then do

```
D:\dev\eap_wildfly\eap-7.4.0>bin\add-user.bat -up standalone\configuration\myfile.properties
```

and add a username:password as usual.

Answer (score 3):

I post here the solution I've found, maybe it could be useful for someone else who has encountered this problem!

I'm using add-user.sh on Jboss Eap 7, trying to add a user to a new security realm I've created I encountered the same issue:

```
jboss-eap-7.0/bin/add-user.sh -r HttpsRealm

What type of user do you wish to add? 
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties) 
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a):
```

It seems my new realm is not recognized, but if I specify also the new properties file I've created related to the realm it works as expected!

```
jboss-eap-7.0/bin/add-user.sh  -r HttpsRealm -up stand-env/stand1/standalone/configuration/https-mgmt-users.properties 

Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'HttpsRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username :
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: In the [JBoss EAP documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/how_to_configure_server_security/index#mgmt_interface_ssl) the command was `add-user.sh -up <path_to_properties> -r <realm>` which did not worked. But specifying the realm (`-r`) first and then user properties (`-up`) worked well. Thanks for posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The add-user utility does not manage new properties files, you must manage separately.

Look : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Add_a_New_Security_Realm.html

> When you add users and roles to this new realm, the information will be stored in a separate file from the default security realms. You can manage this new file using your own applications or procedures.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand yet. Your link is about how I can create the realm, but didn't I do that by editing `standalone.xml`? And what exactly `add-user` does, if I actually cannot, according to you, add users with it?

Comment: Yes! The standalone.xml or domain.xml! The add-user is a default utility and manages default realms.

Comment: However, for your realm work, you must assign it to one of the available management interfaces. I understand you're wan to create your own user management repository ...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what people have said, what finally helped me was.

1. specifying the realm `(-r)` first and then user properties `(-up)`
2. Make sure the user properties file is empty.